# organic chemistry of alkyl halides and alcohols

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, halides

What happens if a primary alcohol that also bears a halide substituent on the alcoholic carbon (the carbon to which the hydroxyl group is attached) when it is reacted with copper at 300 °C ?
   I know primary alcohols, on treatment with copper at 300 °C react to give  aldehydes.  But I am confused what happens if halides are present on the same alcoholic carbon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are correct that [copper metal is a catalyst](http://www.organicchemistry.com/oxidation-methods-of-alcohols/) for alcohol [dissociation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociation_(chemistry)) to aldehyde + $\ce{H2}$.  The reaction of ethanol, for example, can be written as:

$$ \ce{CH3CH2OH  ->[\ce{Cu}~\textrm{metal}][300~^{\circ} \textrm{C}] CH3CHO + H2} $$

2. Your question about halo-substituted alcohols is very interesting, because those species are very unstable.  If I understand you correctly, you are *not* referring to [halohydrins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halohydrin) such as [2-chloroethanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Chloroethanol), which are species that have a halo substituent *beta* to the alcoholic carbon, but rather to species such as 1-chloroethanol where the halo and hydroxyl substituents are on the same carbon atom.
3. *alpha* halo alcohols are very unstable, and tend to eliminate halo-acid and form the corresponding carbonyl compound.  For example, [gaseous chloromethanol spontaneously eliminates hydrogen chloride to form formaldehyde at 296 K (~23 °C) with a half-life of about 300 seconds](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0009261400003845).
4. Thus I think the best answer to your question is that:

   - Halo alcohols like 1-chloroethanol or chloromethanol are *already oxidized* to the same degree as carbonyl compounds.
   - Even before reacting them with copper metal at 300 °C, they are likely to decompose to the carbonyl compound via elimination of hydrogen halide.
   - Unlike the reaction of simple alcohols on hot copper metal, this reaction is not a redox dissociation, but is a simple elimination reaction.$%edit$

Comment: I wouldn’t call that a disproportionation, because different atom kinds get reduced and oxidised. In my understanding, disproportionations only include reactions where atoms of the same element get simultaneously reduced and oxidised such as in $\ce{H2O2 -> H2O + 1/2 O2}$.

Comment: Jan, I can see your point.  What would be an appropriate term?  Dissociation?

Comment: I just edited to make it say dissociation instead of disproportionation.  Thanks for pointing out my non-standard use of the term!